# MySQL Order By not sorting the right data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sort my query records based from a SUMed column using query below:

```
SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS 'name',
    COUNT(o.id_customer) AS 'repeat', FORMAT(SUM(o.total_products),2) AS 'amount'
FROM ps_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY o.id_customer
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

The query above is not returning the right data, more specifically the records returned is not sorted properly.

Can anyone point me to the right direction ? Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You formatted amount with [`FORMAT`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-format-function.php) method

and [`FORMAT`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-format-function.php) return string.

What your query is sorting by data type string instead of number

Comment: I will accept your answer later. You are right, i shouldn't use FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Join that is causing the issue: The following reference might trigger some ideas: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try using subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS 'name',
        COUNT(o.id_customer) AS 'repeat', FORMAT(SUM(o.total_products),2) AS 'amount'
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c ON o.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE o.current_state IN (2,4,5)
    AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
    GROUP BY o.id_customer
) AS o
ORDER BY amount DESC
```